# How do I simulate airflow in Blender?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am trying to build a simple simulation on the Blender physics engine that will simulate airflow in my PC case. Modeling a basic computer tower to scale in Blender was hard enough as it is (for me).

For now I am simply trying to simulate fans in a box. I am ignoring all the internal obstructions.

[image: Blender PC Case Model]

I think the best way to approach this is with a "Smoke" physics simulation, but there's not really an option to make the smoke go in a certain direction at a certain rate (is there?) to simulate in and out fans.

I know this is a very general question with answers already, however I could not find one for this use case.